# It has been a long time + present perfect

Tags: tenses, present-perfect

Could anyone tell me whether my following sentences make sense in English?

1. It has been a long time since **I have played** this game = I haven't played this game for a long time
2. It has been a long time since **I have seen** her = I haven't seen her for a long time

Thanks

Comment: I would say "It's been a long time since I played this game."

Comment: I believe both of your sentences make perfect sense in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both examples are acceptable, but to my native-speaking ear, it might be better and simpler to write:

1. It has been a long time since I [last] played this game.
2. It has been a long time since I [last] saw her.

In these examples, the word "last" would be optional, a clarification, but not necessary.